IOS prioritizes the microphone and the video has low volume (reactjs, web)
I have a web application that plays a video and records the user's microphone at the same time. On IOS the volume of the video being played is low.
Why does it happen and what can I do prevent volume going down automatically? Any help would be appreciated. This will not happen in PC(MacOS, Windows) or Android OS. Has anyone had any similar experience before?

You probably need to configure your audio session to use playAndRecord and defaultToSpeaker. When recording, iOS switches speaker output to the quieter receiver and you need to override this behaviour.
